# Debian installation finished successfully but partitions are %100 free

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

I just tried two times to install Debian 9.8.0 (downloaded from [official repo](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/9.8.0/amd64/iso-dvd/)) but both times despite of successful finish, nothing was installed.

I used [rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create a bootable USB drive. I resized an existing partition to get a ~100GB unallocated space. Disabled both *secure boot* and *fast boot* before going any further. Booted USB drive to go through installation and actually it went smoothly (created one 5GB `swap area` partition at `beginning` and let Debian to decide for the rest).

Each time it finished I removed USB drive but grub didn't show up and Windows booted, directly. Wondered why this happened, I ran `Disk Management` tool and recognized the created partitions are all %100 free:

[image]

I should note that Windows is installed on an SSD and I tried to install Debian on an HDD. And Debian didn't point to Windows while installing grub.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Without extra drivers, Windows won’t know how much space is used inside the Debian partitions. Did you install Grub on the SDD, or the HDD?

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm not sure but as Debian decided where to install it perhaps it is HDD.

Comment: @StephenKitt But how can I find out?

Comment: Try to change the boot order in bios or with F-key (F12?) on startup. Maybe it's just the boot order and grub is installed on hdd.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are getting this information from Windows, right? You should make that clear for non-Windows users, like myself. I've no idea what the Disk Management tool is.